# Change the installation path

Tags: wix

I'm using Wix Toolset for my installation package. I want the user to select the installation path and install my application to that directory but I'm unable to do that. I've tried a few things but they did not worked out. I'll share some of my wix project code and write what I tried. First my code :

```
<wix>
 <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPROOTFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
</wix>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="APPROOTFOLDER" Name="MyApp">
.
.
.
<SetDirectory Id="APPROOTFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyApp\[ProductName]"/>
</Fragment>
```

I dont share the whole project because I think the rest is not relevant to this part. Right now with this setup I can show to user C:\MyApp\test as default path and user can change that by clicking browse. but since I set the directory with `<SetDirectory Id="APPROOTFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyApp\[ProductName]"/>` this line, when the user change the path the installer is still using C:\MyApp\test. I tried to remove that line and it worked, I was able to install where ever I browse but then the installer pick a random default path. Basically I just want to provide a default path as [WindowsVolume]MyApp[ProductName] and also let the user to change that path and install to that path.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I'll write it down instead of deleting the question maybe someone will be in the situation I am right now.

I've changed the
`<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPROOTFOLDER" />`

line with

`<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TARGETDIR" />`

and instead of setting the directory of APPROOTFOLDER I set TARGETDIR.
so instead of this :

`<SetDirectory Id="APPROOTFOLDER" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyApp\[ProductName]"/>`

I did this:

`<SetDirectory Id="TARGETDIR" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyApp\[ProductName]"/>`

I'm not 100% sure what was the problem here tbh, I think the problem was I was not using my root directory Id both in WIXUI_INSTALLDIR property and SetDirectory, I was using a sub directory in my root so probably that was the problem. So if you face a similar problem like this be sure you work with your root..